# Wireshark Decrypting TLS with private key

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark

I have a packet encrypted with TLS in a .pcap file. I also have the private key in a .priv file. How can I  decrypt the .pcap file using Wireshark? I tried going to edit -> preferences -> protocols -> ssl -> edit -> new, but i am not sure what to enter in for the ip address, port? How can I display the corresponding packet in Wireshark to find out the port and ip address? Is this the right way to decrypt the .pcap file in Wireshark using private key? Pls help! Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security, not about programming.

Comment: Oh sry, didn't realize that.. Just wondering, how can I place this question in the security section of stack overflow?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com is the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have transferred the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL/TLS doesn't use public/private keys to encrypt data. The asymmetric keys are used during handshake, and there's a session key generated during handshake. That key is then used for data encryption.

The private key can help in Man-In-The-Middle attack when you can represent yourself as a server with help of the private key and server's certificate.

Comment: Could you please have a look on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227491/non-rsa-tls1-2-packet-decryption