# Non-RSA TLS1.2 Packet decryption

Tags: ssl, encryption, ffmpeg, cryptography, tls1.2

I am trying to decrypt a pcap file. This pcap file contains a capture of an HLS encrypted video stream. The pcap contains TLSv1.2 packets.

Below are some information from the pcap file

> **Server Hello message Cipher Suite:**
>
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.

> EC Diffie-Hellman server Params: pubkey (1)

**The Certificate Status message:**

> Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256
>
> Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA
>
> **Client Key Exchange Message**
>
> EC Diffie-Hellman server Params: pubkey (2)

I tried to follow [this Wireshark SSL decryption tutorial][1]. But it seems that it works only for RSA encryptions.
I have been researching for a while and found [this discussion][2]. I am quoting an extract from this discussion:

> There is an important parameter to mind: decryption of a passively
> recorded session (with a copy of the server private key) works only if
> the key exchange was of type RSA or static DH; with "DHE" and "ECDHE"
> cipher suites, you won't be able to decrypt such a session, even with
> knowledge of the server private key. In that case, you will need
> either the negotiated "master secret", or to use the server private
> key to actively intercept the connection

It's note worthy that I have the client private key. In my case, the client is FFmpeg video streamer (FFplay). I had a look also on the [TLS v1.2 RFC][3].

My question:

Is it possible to do a decryption in this scenario ? If yes, what do I need to have to do so?

Is the decryption done using the client's private key or using the pre_shared_master (i.e. Diffie-Hellman) ?
[1]: https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL
[2]: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117778/how-to-decrypt-ssl-traffic-with-a-packet-sniffer-when-i-have-the-private-key
[3]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246

Comment: Pre-shared secret would be needed. What is client key? Is it a certificate's private key? It's used only for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply really appreciate it! If the pre-shared secret is needed then it's the Diffie-Hellman public keys ? It's not really clear in the RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-8.1.2). The Client private key (FFmpeg key) is found in (https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/415f907ce8dcca87c9e7cfdc954b92df399d3d80/libavformat/tests/rtmpdh.c)..It's a 256 long string static const char *private_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to decrypt in this scenario. That would involve breaking EC Diffie-Hellman.

Decryption is not *directly* performed using the `pre_master_secret` but it is performed *by keys directly derived* from the pre-master secret. That is: the client and server decryption keys that are derived from it by first deriving the `master_secret` and then performing the PRF and dividing the output to the session keys and IV's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I thought from the beginning but wanted to double check with experts. Appreciate your help

Comment: Changed the wording somewhat, there is no such thing as a `pre_shared_master` (in the TLS RFC) and `pre_shared_key` is an entirely different way of establishing session keys.

Comment: No, decryption is not performed using the pre_master_secret. It is performed using the session key.

Comment: @EJP It was explained below that what I meant with it but you're right, changed wording. Other remarks welcome of course.

Answer (score 2):

First, the clients private or public key are not involved in the key exchange in any way but only used to authenticate the client (if requested by the server). What is used in the key exchange are the *servers* private and public key, but only if RSA key exchange is used. For DHE/ECDHE they are not used so private/public key are not sufficient. See [it is possible to decrypt HTTPS with the (private, public) pair if it uses DHE?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71309/it-is-possible-to-decrypt-https-with-the-private-public-pair-if-it-uses-dhe) for the details why this is the case.

What you would need instead of the private key is actually the exchanged key which is unique for each TLS session even if the private key is the same. Some clients can store this key for later use and if your client can do it see [Decrypting TLS Browser Traffic With Wireshark – The Easy Way!](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/) how to proceed then to decrypt the traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply really appreciate it! I had a look on (it is possible to decrypt HTTPS with the (private, public) pair if it uses DHE? ) before asking my question. I'm curious though...How come then the FFplay client is able to decrypt the encrypted video packets? How do you think I would be able to manually compute these pre-shared exchanged keys? The client is opensource code and I'm capturing all the packets so ideally I should be able to decrypt the video traffic manually

Comment: @JosephWahba: ffplay is a TLS client, i.e. it establishes a TLS connection with the server which includes the key exchange. After this key exchange both server and client know the encryption key. But somebody just looking at the traffic does not know the key. I recommend you have a look at one of the various videos on youtube which playful explain diffie hellman key exchange to understand how this works.

Comment: @JosephWahba Why not just modify the client, compile it and have it dump all decrypted data to file?

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Thanks for your suggestion. My concern is how the encryption/decryption happens. Not concerned about the data itself.